# New conditioned column in R data

Tags: r

I'm taking a data mining course and need to manipulate some data to do desired task using randomForest. V1, V2, and V3 are the column names. If V1=A and V2=2, I want R to output "Eureka" to the corresponding row of a new column V4. I want the other values in V4 to be set to "NOPE". The actual data set has 300000 rows and 6 columns. This may seem strange but if I can learn how to do this my problem will be solved. Thanks.

```
  V1  V2   V3   
  A   1    4    
  A   1    8  
  A   2    4  
  A   2    8  
  C   1   10  
  C   1    9  
  C   2   10  
  C   2    9

V1  V2   V3   V4  
A   1    4    NOPE  
A   1    8    NOPE    
A   2    5    Eureka    
A   2    3    Eureka    
C   1   10    NOPE    
C   1    8    NOPE    
C   2   10    NOPE    
C   2    4    NOPE
```

The following code does NOT work.

```
`for(g in 1:8){
if(data$V1[g]=="A"&data$V2[g]==2){
data$V4[g]=Eureka
}else{
data$V4[g]="NOPE"
}
}`
```

Comment: Also, I'm an R novice so please keep it simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could use either numeric index or `ifelse` to create the "V4" column.  `V1=='A' & V2==2` gives a logical index (`TRUE/FALSE`).  Adding `1`, coerces the logical vector to binary (`1/0`) and gives `2/1` corresponding to `TRUE/FALSE`.  This numeric values can be used as index to replace it with `NOPE'/'Eureka'.

```
 df$V4 <- with(df, c('NOPE', 'Eureka')[(V1=='A' & V2==2)+1])
 df
 #  V1 V2 V3     V4
 #1  A  1  4   NOPE
 #2  A  1  8   NOPE
 #3  A  2  4 Eureka
 #4  A  2  8 Eureka
 #5  C  1 10   NOPE
 #6  C  1  9   NOPE
 #7  C  2 10   NOPE
 #8  C  2  9   NOPE
```

Or using `ifelse`

```
 df$V4 <- with(df, ifelse(V1=='A' & V2==2, 'Eureka', 'NOPE'))
```

Another option would be `data.table`.  Convert the "data.frame" to "data.table" (`setDT`).  Create column (`V4`) with value `NOPE`.  The rows of V4 that meets the condition (`V1=='A' & V2==2`) is assigned to `Eureka`

```
 library(data.table)
 setDT(df)[,V4:='NOPE'][V1=='A' & V2==2, V4:='Eureka'][]
```

Regarding the error in your code, 'Eureka' should be quoted.  It is better to use `vectorized` methods rather than loops.

```
 for(g in 1:8){
  if(df$V1[g]=='A' & df$V2[g]==2){
  df$V4[g] <- 'Eureka'
    }
   else{
  df$V4[g] <- 'NOPE'
  }
 }
 df$V4
 #[1] "NOPE"   "NOPE"   "Eureka" "Eureka" "NOPE"   "NOPE"   "NOPE"   "NOPE"
```

#### data

```
 df <- structure(list(V1 = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "C", "C", "C", "C"), 
 V2 = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), V3 = c(4L, 8L, 4L, 
 8L, 10L, 9L, 10L, 9L)), .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3"), class = 
"data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

Comment: @mbs1 `df` is the dataframe object

Answer (score 0):

Set the vector to the defautl value, then replaced the correct instances with the new value using logical indexing.

```
data$V4 <- "Nope"
data$V4[ data$V1[g]=="A" & data$V2[g]==2] <- "Eureka"
```